# Recursively run through a vector in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm just starting to play with Clojure.

How do I run through a vector of items?

My naive recursive function would have a form like the classic map eg.

```
(defn map [f xs] (
  (if (= xs [])
      []
      (cons (f (first xs)) (map f (rest xs))
  )
))
```

The thing is I can't find any examples of this kind of code on the web. I find a lot of examples using built-in sequence traversing functions like for, map and loop. But no-one doing the raw recursive version.

Is that because you SHOULDN'T do this kind of thing in Clojure? (eg. because it uses lower-level Java primitives that don't have tail-call optimisation or something?)?

Comment: You mention tail call optimization, but note that Clojure does *not* have tail call optimization except explicitly with [`recur`](http://clojure.org/special_forms#recur).

Comment: Don't redefine `map`, it already exists. Look near the top of `(source map)` and you'll see the code identical to what you wrote, just wrapped in a `lazy-seq`. If you want an eager-version, use `mapv`. The reason you don't see a lot of explicit recursion is that there are higher level functions like `reduce`, `map`, etc. that take care of many of the use cases with more expressive power.

Comment: ... so the answer is *yes, you SHOULDN'T do this kind of thing in Clojure*. By the way, by using `when-let`, the standard `map` code implicitly returns `nil` upon an empty sequence. When `nil` is asked to be a sequence, it masquerades as an empty one, so restoring order. This is called *nil punning*. The relevant extract is `(defn map [f coll]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [s (seq coll)]
      (cons (f (first s)) (map f (rest s))))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure re-uses stack frames **only with tail-recurstion and only when you use the explicit `recur`** call. Everything else will be stack consuming. The above map example is not tail recursive because the cons happens after the recursive call so it can't be TCO'd in any language. If you switch it to use the continuation passing style and use an explicit call to `recur` instead of `map` then you should be good to go.

Comment: ... or use something like (simplifying the standard `mapv`): `(defn mapv [f coll] (reduce (fn [v o] (conj v (f o))) [] coll))`

Answer (score 2):

When you say "run through a vector" this is quite vague; as Clojure is a lisp and thus specializes in sequence analysis and manipulation, the beauty of using this language is that you don't think in terms "run through a vector and then do something with each element," instead you'd more idiomatically say "pull this out of a vector" or "transform this vector into X" or "I want this vector to give me X".

It is because of this type of perspective in lisp languages that you will see so many examples and production code that doesn't just loop/recur through a vector but rather specifically goes after what is wanted in a short, idiomatic way. Using simple functions like `reduce` `map` `filter` `for` `into` and others allow you to *elegantly* move over a sequence such as a vector while *simultaneously* doing what you want with the contents. In most other languages, this would be at least 2 different parts: the loop, and then the actual logic to do what you want.

You'll often find that if you think about sequences using the more imperative idea you get with languages like C, C++, Java, etc, that your code is about 4x longer (at least) than it would otherwise be if you first thought about your plan in a more functional approach.